# best way to tackle: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status

Tags: reactjs, rust, cors, preflight

ah yes, yet another preflight error. I've been trying to get rid of this for a while now.

So im building a rust-react project and while making a post or even get request for that matter, im facing this same error.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/create' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

The host is `http://127.0.0.1:8000` and the react origin is `http://localhost:3000` . I've enabled CORS in rust, with the requied headers but to no avail. Every request in my application, needs to be accompanied with a global key in the headers to access or post any sort of data. Simply put, any interaction with the server requires this key.

here's my rust code,

```
pub struct CORS;

#[rocket::async_trait]
impl Fairing for CORS {
    fn info(&self) -> Info {
        Info {
            name: "Add CORS headers to responses",
            kind: Kind::Response
        }
    }

    async fn on_response<'r>(&self, _request: &'r Request<'_>, response: &mut Response<'r>) {
        response.set_header(Header::new("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000"));
        response.set_header(Header::new("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PATCH, OPTIONS"));
        response.set_header(Header::new("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Global-Api-Key"));
        response.set_header(Header::new("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true"));
        response.set_header(Header::new("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400"));
    }
}
```

And heres the axios instance

```
const authSend = axios.create({
    method: 'post',
    baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
    data: {},
    headers: {
        'Global-Api-Key': key,
        Accept: 'application/json',
    }
})
```

What i could find by scratching the internet so far is, before any request, your browser send an `OPTIONS` request to verify the headers before making data available for remote access. So in order to handle this, i simply need to send an HTTP ok response from the server whenever the method is `OPTIONS` . But wouldnt that defeat the whole purpose of the request in the first place? I know the other solutions on the internet like using a proxy or simply turning off CORS isn't good practice which is why i haven't tried them yet.

I need to know if sending such response is the most reliable way to tackle this error or if theres something more to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out that was the only way to make things work. Despite looking for more answers, I sent an 200 OK response and things are good. another issue i was facing was, the `axios.create()` function used to create custom axios instance wasnt passing the required headers properly whereas when you simply call the axios function like

```
axios({method: 'post', 
      url: 'your url', 
      your data, 
      headers: { 'Global-Api-Key': key,}
})
```

It did the job. I dont know how or what the issue is with custom instances and passing headers. [this](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/891) is the page i referred and they stated the same problem with the above solution.